# Ruby on Rails FATAL_ERROR process out of memory exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a sample rails app with a User model.
The commands i used are:

- `sudo rails new app`
- `sudo rails generate scaffold User name:string`
- `sudo rake db:migrate`
- `sudo rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
- `sudo bundle install`
- `sudo bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
- `sudo rails server -e production`

When i try to run my application at production mode, i get this error: http://pastebin.com/tNvm9jfm

Also i tried compilation at real time (`config.assets.compile = true`).The result was the same.

Comment: did you not do any changes to the code?

Comment: The only change i did (which i don't think it matters) is to change source `'https://rubygems.org'` to `'http://rubygems.org'`. Everything is auto generated. I get the same error when i try to run in production mode another application i have

Comment: Seems like a nodejs problem during the compilation from the error. Rails uses a javascript engine to compile the assets. Try adding gem 'therubyracer' in your gemfile to see if it works with rubyracer and try to compile again and test nodejs to see if it works.

Comment: @JohnDel Yes that's it. Now it worked. If you want post an answer to accept it and vote up.